# Bulk edit libraries from different websites

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type

We are working with different Web Sites which are coming from the same template. All website have the same Libraries and Content Types. It worked very well until yesterday. Now we need to change one of the Library on all websites. We have up to 73 websites which have to change manually.

Is it possible to change all libraries at once? Is there a software or anything else?

Comment: You could use PowerShell to automate the process.

Comment: What is the change you are trying to make?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell as below

```
$site = get-spsite http://sitecollectionurl

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    $libraryName = "DocumentLibrary"

    $list = $web.Lists[$libraryName]

    if($list) {
        #logic to update the library; like modifying field information etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all we have to rename the libraries, the second change is to add a new content type to all libraries and the third change is to make a multiple textfield into a single line of text.
Thanks in advance, know i have to build me a script which includes all my changes.